# How to create a rapier.js heightfield from a threejs 3d plane

Tags: three.js

So I am currently working with threejs and I created a plane and applied a heightmap to it. How can I generate a rapier.js heightfield from it. I require the height of all the vertices but I need them to be stored in a column-major array. How can I access the height of the vertices, because I used buffer geometry but they all seem to be randomly selected or I simply misunderstood everything. If anybody knows how to help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Heightmap is actually applied on GPU. And Rapier works on CPU. You can't directly access the altered vertices heights.

I would approach this problem in these 2 ways -

1. Change geometry on CPU and generate heightField collider from it. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/github/tamani-coding/threejs-rapier3d-character-terrain-movement?file=src%2Findex.ts)

   a) Generate terrain on CPU by changing geometry vertices based on the heightmap image. For a given pixel setting (assume column-major arrays):

   ```
   z = HeightMap[pixelIndex] * HeightScale;
   planeMesh.geometry.setZ(pixelIndex, z);
   ```

   b) `heights` in heightfield collider can then be generated from `z` value of the geometry

   ```
   const heights = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < positionAttributes.count; i++) {
     heights.push(positionAttributes.getZ(i));
   }
   ```
2. Keep using heightMap and make the heights array similar to step `b` above with the same math as present in step `a`. Get the grayscale value from each pixel of the image and use it in heightField

```
const heights = [];
for (let i = 0; i < positionAttributes.count; i++) {
  z = HeightMap[pixelIndex] * HeightScale;
  heights.push(z);
}
```